# How can I plot this barplot?

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a barplot in R, but I'm running into a lot of trouble getting it to plot.

here's the data I'm trying to plot:

```
> frac
      P462   D463    N473    Y475   L443   F460  Y442
S19 47.118 24.612   0.000   0.000  0.000  0.000 0.000
E23  5.863  0.000   0.000   0.000  0.000  0.000 0.000
Q24 82.248  0.526 142.232   9.774  0.000  0.000 0.000
T27 68.375  0.000   0.000 211.713 90.094 33.319 8.059
F28  0.000  0.000   0.000 158.803  0.000  0.000 0.000

> dput(frac)
structure(list(P462 = c(47.118, 5.863, 82.248, 68.375, 0), D463 = c(24.612, 
0, 0.526, 0, 0), N473 = c(0, 0, 142.232, 0, 0), Y475 = c(0, 0, 
9.774, 211.713, 158.803), L443 = c(0, 0, 0, 90.094, 0), F460 = c(0, 
0, 0, 33.319, 0), Y442 = c(0, 0, 0, 8.059, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("S19", 
"E23", "Q24", "T27", "F28"))
```

My question is, how can I plot the data so that I get a series of bar plots where the x-axis is "S19", "E23", "Q24", etc. and the y-axis is a stacked barplot where each column of values is plotted (like the plot below but with all the other rows in the table graphed in the same way)?

[image: sample]

Whenever I try `barplot(frac)` it always tells me `Error in barplot.default(frac) : 'height' must be a vector or a matrix`

If anyone would please provide some insight into how this can be done, I would really appreciate it!!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you provide your data as a data.frame? try pasting  `frac <- data.frame(...)` or `dput(frac)` into the question

Comment: Just did it! I put it right underneath the original data output

Comment: Try `barplot(t(frac))`

Comment: That works! Thanks a ton jay.sf!!